# Truncating a Float Value Without Using SetRoundingMode()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am truncating a float here.But my value is getting rounded.I do not want that.E.g If my value is 12.989 -> it should be printed as 12.98 only. Can someone help
I cannot use decimal format's SetRoundingMode because that is supported from java 1.6 only.
Mine is 1.5 JDK. CAn someone help me out without using SetRoundingMode() Method????

```
        String pattern = "##,##0.00";        
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;      

        double fPart; 
        Float value=233.989f;
        String dstr = String.valueOf(value);
        dstr = dstr.substring(dstr.indexOf(".")+1);
        Long db = Long.valueOf(dstr);
        if(db > 0){
            df.applyPattern(pattern);
            System.out.println("input="+value+", fPart="+dstr);
        }        

        String output = df.format(value);

    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use old school trick, multiply by 10^n, truncate, divide by 10^n:

```
float x = 233.989f;
x = (float)(Math.floor(x * 100) / 100);
```

I've also experimented with BigDecimal:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(5, RoundingMode.FLOOR)
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(233.989, mc);
System.out.println(decimal);
```

It does the job but you have to specify total number of digits. You can't just say I want 2 decimal places and I don't care about digits left of decimal point. That's way first parameter of `MathContext` is 5, not 2. If you opt for this approach, you can quickly calculate non decimal digits with `Math.Ceil(Math.log10(x))`.

Note:

- When dividing (first approach) at least one of operands must be floating point (float or double)
- When working with strings (you code), it's not safe to presume that '.' is decimal separator
- Truncating decimals with Math.floor only works for positive values

Comment: What if you dont know what the numbers are and stil you  want to achieve the pattern  ?

Comment: The 'old school trick' fails over 90% of the time. You can't truncate floating point values to a specific number of decimal places because they don't have decimal places to truncate.

Comment: @Azfar: What do you mean you have to know the numbers? You can always calculate `setPrecision` for `MathContext` object. Do I have to clarify how to do that?
@EJP: If we change constants a little bit, both multiplication and division would be performed with double precision: `Math.floor(x * 100.0) / 100`. AFAIK `double` doesn't show loss of precision for first 15 digits and I'm pretty that's more than enough for 99% of non-scientific calculus.

Comment: @EmperorOrionii the old trick is not working when the number of digits already 2  like Math.floor(9.62 * 100 ) /100 will result 9.61

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understood you problem correclty. But If you want to truncate without rounding up or down, you can use just like 
`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
df.format(12.912385);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions to get the second digit after "." and then subtract the string from the beginning to that position and then transform the string into a float or double.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("regular expression");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("your string");

if(matcher.find())
{
    int poz_begin = matcher.start();
    int poz_end = matcher.end();
}
```

Comment: on noes, not regular expressions.